# Asp.net MVP - Creating dynamic controls, where?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5, mvp

So, I'm attempting to rewrite an old asp.net app and thought I'd do it in in MVP this time.
The app displays a dynamically generated form by placing labels and input fields in a table.

What I get from my Model is a list of entities that describe what control's should be rendered.

Now this list needs to be converted into a table with a lable and control on each row, but I can't decide where and how to do this.

These are the scenario's I could think of, but I have no idea which one is right according to MVP:

- For each item create a table row in the presenter and call `View.AddRow(row)`
- Create a list of table rows in the presenter and call `View.AddRows(list)`
- For each item call `View.CreateRow(info)`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of the MVP pattern is to separate the concerns between the view and the presenter. The  presenter only has to set the list of entities and whether the data is presented as a table using a GridView, Repeater etc is the concern of the view.

If I were doing what you would describe I would use a 'view model' class to act as a wrapper for creating the controls:

```
public class DynamicControlViewModel
{
    public enum ControlTypes
    {
        TextBox,
        DropDown,
        CheckBox
    }

    public string LabelValue { get; set; }
    public ContrlTypes ControlType { get; set; }
}
```

My View would look as follows:

```
interface IDynamicControlsView
{
    IEnumerable<DynamicControlViewModel> DynamicControls { set; }
}
```

And the presenter:

```
// This method would be called within your Presenter
public override void Initialize()
{
      _view.DynamicControls = ConvertDataToViewModel(data); // your method to fetch the data would replace 'data'
}
```

The property setter on the view implementation (the .ASPX code behind) would look as:

```
  public IEnumerable<DynamicControlViewModel> DynamicControls
    {
        set
        {
            foreach (DynamicControlViewModel model in value)
            {
                // build up user controls here....
                switch (model.ControlType)
                {
                    case DynamicControlViewModel.ContrlTypes.TextBox:
                        // add text box
                        break;
                    case DynamicControlViewModel.ContrlTypes.DropDown:
                        // add drop down
                        break;
                    case DynamicControlViewModel.ContrlTypes.CheckBox:
                        // add checkbox
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the view model would make unit testing easier and keep a cleaner separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is an important difference with what you describe and that is that the data needs to be converted to Control's so I can't simply bind it to a repeater or something. So the question is if I should create these Control's on the Presenter or on the View.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more complete code example. Is that more what you had in mind? The controls should be a created in the view. If in your presenter you have to add a reference to WebControls it's usually an indication things are getting too tightly coupled.

Comment: Ok, so Control creation on the View? Got it, thanks. Any other opinions are still much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, control creation in the view, but be sure that any of the logic to determine what controls to create should live in the presenter i.e. try to keep logic out of the view. Another opinion would be to mark my answer as accepted if my above code example does what you need :-) If you need further clarification of the code examples please ask.